# How we can capture entire screen screenshot using android application via programming

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg, screenshot, android-mediaprojection

Can anyone having idea how we can capture entire screen screenshot including other application overlay menu and toast using android application programming not for adb commands and manual button press.

I have went through some of the code which is taking screenshot excluding toast and other application overlay displayed on my screen.

Below code is only capturing activity view screenshot not capturing any other app overrlay menu and toast. Mostly because of `val v1: View = window.decorView` this line.

```
val mPath: String = context.cacheDir.absolutePath + "/temp_${System.currentTimeMillis()}" + ".png"
// create bitmap screenshot
val v1: View = window.decorView
v1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.drawingCache)
v1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
val imageFile = File(mPath)
val outputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
val quality = 100
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream)
outputStream.flush()
outputStream.close()
```

Also try to execute command to capture screenshot via app programming but not get succeed,

```
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
val os = DataOutputStream(process.outputStream)
val cmd= "exec-out screencap"
os.writeBytes(cmd)
os.close()
```

**Requirement**

- Listener to identify if any other app displaying overlay menu.
- I would like to capture screenshot when any other application overlay is displayed on my screen and screenshot must contains other application overlay.

Please let me know how can i archive this. I really appreciate for your single reply or answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that you tagged this question with [android-mediaprojection]. I'm not sure if that means you've tried it yet, but I'm fairly sure that it's the only practical method to do this, since you don't really have any way to get direct access to other app's `View`s or `Window`s. [Here's the dev page for it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/media-projection), if you'd not seen it yet.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for comment. Yes i have not seen yet and about to see!!! I have added tag because I have doubt if it support or not? If we are using mediaprojection api for screenshot then there is user consent on every request of screenshot or it's one time only like run time permission. Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really sure, to be honest. I've only ever used it once, long ago, for a very quick and hacky solution to some one-off issue I was having at the time. As I recall, I pretty much copied/pasted a working example and just made a few minor changes to suit my setup, so I'm not at all familiar with the details, offhand.

Comment: @MikeM. Okay no problem. Let me explore their API will publish answer if will get success!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
public Bitmap getFulllScreenshot() {
   View v= findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
   v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
   v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
   v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight()); 

   v.buildDrawingCache(true);
   Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
   v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
   return b;
}
```

Comment: I have check your solution but unfortunately this is not capturing entire screen screenshot including toast and overlay menu.